# 'any' doesn't raise error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, any

I was playing around then I noticed this:

```
>>> l = input().split()
1 25 11 4
>>> any(s == s[::-1] for s in l)
True
>>> s == s[::-1] for s in l
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Why does `any(s == s[::-1] for s in l)` work if `s == s[::-1] for s in l` itself would raise error?

Comment: Please explain why I am not supposed to ask this question.

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Is that seriously the reason they downvoted me? They should at least be aware that they can edit...

Comment: It might be, I can't say because I was not the one downvoting you. But "they can edit" is not a good excuse. You want an answer, so it is up to you to present your question (and especially the code) in due form, so that the possible answerers can copy and paste your code to run it themselves.

Comment: @Matthias If you look closely, I already edited. I wasn't aware that you frown upon images. If they downvote me, they should let me know what's wrong with question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
any(s == s[::-1] for s in l)
```

is the same as:

```
any((s == s[::-1] for s in l))
```

and:

```
(s == s[::-1] for s in l)
```

is not a syntax error. It is a generator expression. As you have found parenthesis are required around generator expressions except when they occur as the only argument to a function call.

Answer (score 1):

To complete Dan D. answer,

```
(s == s[::-1] for s in l)
```

is like :

```
def your_function():
    for s in l:
        yield s == s[::-1]
```